# Does Spotify support 3rd party development for Plugins in the Spotify app/application itself?

Tags: plugins, spotify

Does Spotify support 3rd party development for Plugins in the Spotify app/application itself (ie. not asking about 3rd party apps connecting to Spotify)?

Answer (score 1):

No, Spotify doesn't support third-party applications in its app.

Spotify used to allow third-party applications inside the Desktop app for Mac and Windows, but removed this feature in 2014. For more information on Spotify's developer tools, see the [Developer site](https://developer.spotify.com).